# Optimize a mysql query with left join, group by and order by

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have this query not written by me that I have to optimize:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.itemid
              , r.catid
              , i.title
              , i.owner
              , i.image
              , i.background
              , i.icon 
           FROM jos_sobi2_cat_items_relations r
           LEFT 
           JOIN jos_sobi2_item i
             ON i.itemid = r.itemid 
          WHERE
              ( i.published = 1 
            AND r.catid > 1 

            AND  ( i.publish_down > '2016-10-26 13:08:02' 
                OR i.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
                 ) 

            AND i.itemid IN ( SELECT itemid 
                                FROM jos_sobi2_item 
                               WHERE ( published = 1

                                   AND ( publish_down > '2016-10-26 13:08:02' 
                                      OR publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
                                       )

                                     )
                            )
              )
          GROUP 
             BY i.itemid 
          ORDER 
             BY i.publish_up DESC 
          LIMIT 0,14
```

This is the explain mysql command:

[image]

The "items" table does have just the primary key on itemid field.
The "relation" table does have these 3 indexes:

```
- catid,itemid PRIMARY BTREE
- itemid BTREE
- catid BTREE
```

I saw that if I remove the DISTINCT or the GROUP BY clauses the query is fast, otherwise it takes more than 1 minute to be executed.

The first thought I had was to remove the DISTINCT clause, since the GROUP BY clause already does the job. But I am not sure.

Any helps about how optimize it?

Thanks.

Comment: This query would not even run on other databases, including some versions of MySQL, because you are selecting non aggregate columns.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Unfortunately is not written by me, thats why I asked for an help

Comment: Does `published = 1` imply that `publish_down = '0...' cannot happen?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN i`, then you `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` `i....` -- `LEFT JOIN` delivers NULLs when the rows are missing.  Maybe `LEFT` should be removed??

Comment: Which table is `publish_down` in?  Please qualify all column names.

Comment: Clean up the query _first_.  Then we can discuss speeding it up !

Comment: I cleaned up the query.

Answer (score -1):

At first, items.itemid IN (...) is redundant, You already have these conditions i the query. You do not need LEFT JOIN, items row is in the where condition, it can not be missing. You do not need distinct or group by either, [relation.itemid, relation.catid] is primary key, it can not contain duplicates. So the result is:

```
SELECT relation.itemid, relation.catid, title, owner, image, background, icon FROM
    `jos_sobi2_cat_items_relations` AS relation
JOIN `jos_sobi2_item` AS items ON relation.itemid = items.itemid WHERE
    `published` = '1' AND
    relation.catid > 1 AND
    (`publish_down` > '2016-10-26 13:08:02' OR `publish_down` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' )     
ORDER BY items.publish_up DESC, relation.itemid, relation.catid LIMIT 0, 14
```

You can compare the result to the original query. I added order on relation.itemid and relation.catid so that the result is deterministic. You can add index on items.publish_up to speed up the query if needed.

Comment: To get the same results I had to add the DISTINCT and GROUP BY clauses, and the problem is still there. The query is too slow.

Comment: I expected the engine would automatically group by all columns in the select, I did not realize that mysql actually interprets it in different way. In that case the queries are not equal. But I would recommend You to rethink what Your query should do, because it is not determinic as You have it now. It can not be optimized, because its results are unpredictable.